# Target and project settings in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, build-settings, ios-targets

I wanted to know if the project settings will override the target settings in xcode. So when i click on project i can click on build settings but also when i click on target settings i can select its build settings.

1. So when i choose the build settings in project does it automatically set the targets settings to the same values if i dont set it in the targets build settgings?
2. Can you give me an example as to why i would set different values for the same items in the projects build menu and the targets build menu?

Comment: Your question is probably a bit broad, but here is a resource.  http://pewpewthespells.com/blog/using_xcode_targets.html

Comment: Thanks ill look at the link. If i get my answers answered ill post it as the answer for the question